# Showing number of comments for the question

Tags: feature-request, comments

How about showing number of comments posted on that answer page. Because sometime it says 0 answer but the person who asked the question might already got the answer from other user's comments. I know that's not always a case.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that's not always a case.

You answered yourself...

Comments are *not* answers, if a comment answers a question, the commenter will be encouraged to post it as an answer and probably will become an answer soon.

Also keep in mind that the number of the comments is *not* an indication of an answer. Anyway you'll have to go to the question to see it there're answers in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Comments often come thick and fast, most question getting 2-3 comments in the first few mins of the question being posted. And so it's likely showing the *comment count change* on the question listing page would probably be far too resource heavy as it would be constantly changing for thousands of questions.

Especially given that they are just comments, and don't necessarily add any useful content, so the comment count won't really add much in the way of useful data.
Comments are really supposed to be used just to enable us to get to an answer.

> the person who asked the question might already got the answer from other user's comments

So why do you want to see comment count?
Would a high comment count stop you visiting the question? Or a low count make you visit it thinking an answer might be possible?

I can't see any useful pattern based on comment count.
Whether a question has 0 comments, or 50 comments, it has *no answer*, so you or someone else can provide one, so showing comment count doesn't really provide anything useful.

In fact, if comment count was available, users might not stop by the question thinking that those 5, 10, etc, comments will likely have sorted it, or be in the process of sorting it, and so we *potentially* risk losing answers being posted as a result.