# Why are people who are not on the SO team answering questions about feature-requests like they were part of the SO team?

Tags: discussion, meta

I find it rather strange and unfair that people who are not on the Stack Overflow team answer questions about feature-requests like they were responsible for it.

Until yesterday I thought that if someone posts a feature-request the real SO developers will say whether it's possible or not to implement it and we (the users) just give our feedback about it, whether we would like or not or how etc. and not the users who think that it isn't and won't be done.

But it turns out that some people answer questions directed to the developers on their behalf and we don't get the chance to hear the real voice.

Can we know the list of people whose voice really counts or who represent the developers so that we can estimate the *value* of an answer?

I really would like to here the opinion of the Stack Overflow team about things that concern the website rather then of some casual people who simply say *no, it's not possible* or *no, we can't do that* when they really have no influence upon the decision.

---

You've asked for examples so I picked only a few:

Both answers sound like both users were on the team:

[May we have some "canned comments"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283114/may-we-have-some-canned-comments/283246#283246)
[May we have some "canned comments"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283114/may-we-have-some-canned-comments/283218#283218)

[Showing number of comments for the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281020/showing-number-of-comments-for-the-question/281021#281021)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283580/number-of-daily-reviewable-items-based-on-audit-results#comment142783_283580

The actual reason for starting this discussion:
[Automatically open jsFiddle in a new tab?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276173/automatically-open-jsfiddle-in-a-new-tab#comment143844_276175)

All of those answers sound like the people writing them were in charge.

It's never clear whether an answer/comment is a user's or an employee's opinion.

Some kind of indicator for employees would be in feature-request topics very usefull so that you know who's actually answering/commenting and if really is a team member of if someone just thinks he can write like he was.

Comment: People post answers on these to give further input on whether they (and via votes, the community) agree with the feature request and think it's worth the time and effort. Nothing about this prevents developers from coming along and posting an answer as well.

Comment: I've nothing against people comments and answers when they express their opinion about an idea but many of them talk as they were who decide it whether it's possible or not to implement something.

Comment: The whole point of posting feature requests on Meta sites is to *solicit feedback from the community*. You can see from votes on answers what the community thinks about the various opinions and feedback. You can also look at the user reputation for a rough estimate of how much experience they have working with the site and the community.

Comment: Some examples would be helpful. I haven't seen this behavior you're referring to. Note that not all SE developers have the moderator star by their name, so these may actually be developers you're talking about.

Comment: But **no one but the employees** can speak for the developers. Most employees that post here have a moderator diamond next to their name (but not all); look at their user profile, it'll state in their About Me that they are employees.

Comment: @ChrisHayes It happens. Here - for example - are my answers on feature requests on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=user%3a162704%20is%3aanswer%20%5bfeature-request%5d

Comment: But take into account some of us have been working with Stack Exchange software for a *very long time indeed* and have a pretty good idea as to what can and cannot be done.

Comment: @Yannis I scanned through 6 or 7 of your answers and they don't seem to fit the question asked here. t3chb0t seems to feel people are saying whether features are *technically feasible* on StackExchange. Your answers seem to be about whether they're good ideas or worth implementing, which is in line with behavior that t3chb0t has already acknowledged is desirable.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Then, I'd also like to see concrete examples of what t3chb0t has in mind. A couple of times I may have commented on the technical feasibility of a feature, but I'm not exactly a regular user (I have a direct line to SE employees through the mod chat room, and at times I may have a bit of inside info).

Comment: And depending how far back you go, you may find answers by **former** employees who answered when they were an employee ([waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles) comes to mind but there are a few others)

Comment: None of the examples you've just added match what you described at all. These are community members giving their view on community matters. The only one remotely technical is the last one (auto-open links in new tab), except it's not technical in a way that's unique to Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 11):

This question comes with some misconceptions that should be addressed.

#### Users *do* have an influence on decisions by the staff

> I really would like to here the opinion of the Stack Overflow team about things that concern the website rather then of some casual people who simply say no, it's not possible or no, we can't do that when **they really have no influence upon the decision.**

(Emphasis added. Typos in the original.)

The community of users does have an influence upon the decisions that are made by the SE staff. It does not mean that the popular opinion is going to win every time. However, that that the staff is not *always* going to bow the the popular opinion does *not entail* that the community has *no* influence. For instance, users have suggested new features that were implemented.

When it comes to *declining* feature requests, while I can't talk for SE developers I would not be surprised if it happened that a dev thought at first glance that a feature would be nice to have, only to be convinced otherwise because a user made a good case against it on Meta. Some feature requests have far-reaching effects that may not always be easy to discern, even by the developers.

#### Determining the possibility of implementing a feature does not *always* require dev knowledge

I have an example. Suppose someone suggests that when gold badge holders in a tag used on the question vote on answers to this question, there should be a mark indicating that a gold badge holder gave their seal of approval or disapproval. (This is inspired by a [real request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282988/allow-gold-tag-badge-holders-to-corroborate-an-answer) that was made a while back.) It is *impossible* to implement this request, as expressed above, without at the same time harming vote anonymity. While the name of the gold badge holder would not be slapped next to the mark, a) the set of gold badge holders in the tags used on the question is much smaller than the set of users on SO, and b) in all likelihood the gold badge holder would be someone who is active in the tags on the question, c) low traffic tags have a very small number of gold badge holders. So there are cases where it would be fairly easy to guess who voted. No, not a 100% chance but good guess nonetheless. **I don't need to be a developer to make a good case that it is impossible to implement the request without harming vote anonymity.**

By and large, this is the kind of "impossibility" that most feature requests fail: it is not that they are impossible, period, but they are impossible to implement without having undesirable effects A, B, C, D, etc. which don't need developer knowledge to discern.

Those cases where developers are in a special position to argue for impossibility is when the **development cost** of implementing the feature request is just too high. "Yeah, we could do what you want but we'd have to redesign SO from the ground up." However, even here it is possible for non-developers to produce good answers: people experienced on Meta have read previous answers from developers and can infer from those answers, and the Data Explorer gives us an idea of how things are organized behind the scenes.

And if a user posts incorrect information an SE employee can comment on it or post an answer of their own. I've seen this happen. I've seen answers deleted by their authors because they were based on a complete misconception of the architecture of SO.

Answer (score 8):

A list of employees can be found [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/team). Clicking on their portrait will lead to their stackexchange profile. For example, from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

> #### Moderators act as a liaison between the community and Stack Exchange the company.
>
> Site moderators can also escalate issues of moderation by contacting
> the Stack Exchange team for guidance and administrative or technical
> tasks.
>
> Additionally, moderators can help draw extra attention to bugs,
> feature requests, or other issues that affect their site if the
> community is unable to resolve the issue on their meta site.
>
> Site moderators are distinguished from normal users by the diamond (♦)
> displayed beside their user names. Some Stack Exchange employees also
> have diamonds next to their user names; these are usually developers
> or community managers, or other employees who work directly with our
> users to resolve bugs or address other community concerns. Stack
> Exchange employees identify themselves as such in their user profiles.

If the user is not an employee, like with anything else on the Internet, take it with a grain of salt. You are not forced to accept somebody's opinion as fact. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)'s are not just for employees either, the whole community can chip in. As with anything else, some users have stronger opinions than others or more weight in their say due to experience or knowledge, but you can always ignore them if you wish.

Comment: The list of employees link appears to be broken – it now redirects to a general company page without employee list.

Comment: Partial list: https://stackoverflow.com/company/management

Answer (score 1):

From the question:

```
But it turns out that some people answer questions directed to the 
developers on their behalf and we don't get the chance to hear the
real voice.
...
I really would like to here the opinion of the Stack Overflow team
about things that concern the website...
```

Everyone can answer every question. Many questions have more than one answer. But one answer can be chosen specially by the questioner.

All this means that you always get a chance to hear the real voice. Any question that is still open can always get an answer from a SO employee. SO can always answer if SO wants to answer. The answers of others do not mean that they want to pretend they are SO, just that they want to contribute to the discussion.

I would also like to hear the opinion of the SO team more often. But what can I do if they don't want to/cannot give it? Nothing, really. So everything should stay as it is.